# System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.DataAdapter()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i am getting this error " System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.DataAdapter()' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

I am trying to use DataAdaptar class in my controller in MVC 2..

Umair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The constructor is protected because this class is not intended to be instantiated by user code. You could use the specific adapter for your database. For example for SQL Server that would be: [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this help Darin Dimitrov.. 

Then how can I migrate data from MySQL to Sql using SqlDataAdaptar class??